# RavenDB - How to add a WKT circle shape to an index?

Tags: indexing, ravendb, spatial

How can I add a computed shape to my index?

I have a class

```
public class Partner
{
   public double Latitude { get; set; }
   public double Longitude { get; set; }
   public double WorkingRadius { get; set; }
   public double WorkingRadiusShape 
   { 
      get
      { 
         return string.Format("Circle({0},{1}, d={2})", Latitude, Longitude, WorkingRadius);
      }
   }
}
```

with the following index

```
public class PartnersByLocation : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Partner>
{
   public PartnersByLocation()
   {
      Map = partners => from doc in partners
                              select new
                              {
                                WorkingRadiusShape = doc.WorkingRadiusShape
                              };

      Spatial(x => x.WorkingRadiusShape, options => options.Geography.Default());
    }
 }
```

I rebuild and run my application, but the index PartnersByLocation is empty. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. The index reports no errors, and I have checked that the collection of Partners has values set for the properties that are written into the WorkingRadiusShape property. Is there something fundamentally wrong with my syntax or approach?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

```
Map = partners => from doc in partners
                              where doc.AbilityKeyIds != null
                              select new
                              {
                                WorkingRadiusShape = string.Format("Circle({0},{1}, d={2})", doc.Latitude, doc.Longitude, doc.WorkingRadius)
                              };



Spatial(x => x.WorkingRadiusShape, options => options.Geography.Default());
```

The key was to move assign the WorkingRadiusShape at indexing, otherwise the property only gets updated on document read/write. Therefore if there are any deprecated/invalid entries they will not be updated when the index is written, and indexing will break. In my case I was storing 10000 for WorkingRadius in one of my Partner entries. This value was causing the indexing to break since there is a maximum value of 180 that can be passed as 'd'. Be aware of that maximum value when assigning your shapes.